# Project Euler #16 - Sum of all digits of 2^1000

Tags: java, programming-challenge

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

```
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger("2");
    big = big.pow(1000);
    String num = big.toString();
    System.out.println(num);
    int result = 0;
    for(char i : num.toCharArray()) {
        result += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What kind of feedback are you looking for? Is there anything about the code you've posted that you're not satisfied with?

Comment: yes, I feel that there is a better way.  instead of converting BigInteger to string and then to charArray and again I return it to int

Comment: Use Character.getNumericalValue(char) instead of Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i)).

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen yeah it's more clear. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks good. I assume this results in correct answer.

- What you can use instead of converting to `String` and back to `int` is to use `divideAndRemainder` method with `10` since we need to treat this as a base 10 number.
- This method is available in `BigInteger` for situations like this.
- We can also directly use BigInteger constants such as `TWO` and `TEN`.

---

**Alternative Implementation**

```
BigInteger big = BigInteger.TWO.pow(1000);
String num = big.toString();
System.out.println(num);

int result = 0;
BigInteger[] components;

components = big.divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
while (components[0].signum() != 0) {
    result += components[1].intValue();
    components = components[0].divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
}
result += components[1].intValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

- <sub>I've used `signum` method here to check if result after integer division is zero.</sub>
- <sub>**Note**: This seems to be creating lot of objects.</sub>

---

**Benchmark with JMH**

After the some discussion in comments with @TorbenPutkonen, I agreed with `TorbenPutkonen` that alternative implementation might be creating more objects. However there is no way to see which implementation performs faster without doing a benchmark.

```
public class X {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(a);
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BenchmarkState {
        BigInteger multiple =  BigInteger.TWO.pow(1000);
        public BenchmarkState() {
            System.out.println(multiple);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public int withDivide(BenchmarkState x) {
        BigInteger[] components;
        components = x.multiple.divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
        int result = 0;
        while (components[0].signum() != 0) {
            result += components[1].intValue();
            components = components[0].divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        result += components[1].intValue();
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public int withChars(BenchmarkState x) {
        String num = x.multiple.toString();
        int result = 0;
        for(char i : num.toCharArray()) {
            result += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public int withCharsNumerical(BenchmarkState x) {
        String num = x.multiple.toString();
        int result = 0;
        for(char i : num.toCharArray()) {
            result += Character.getNumericValue(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public int withCharAt(BenchmarkState x) {
        String num = x.multiple.toString();
        int len = num.length();
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public int withCharsNumericalCharAt(BenchmarkState x) {
        String num = x.multiple.toString();
        int len = num.length();
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result += Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:21:29

Benchmark                    Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
X.withCharAt                thrpt  200  117285.320 ±  644.505  ops/s
X.withChars                 thrpt  200  116882.706 ±  779.233  ops/s
X.withCharsNumerical        thrpt  200  110849.659 ± 3901.095  ops/s
X.withCharsNumericalCharAt  thrpt  200  121480.705 ± 2040.597  ops/s
X.withDivide                thrpt  200   11306.787 ±   35.711  ops/s
```

- This concludes that original version is roughly `10x` faster than `divideAndRemainder`
- Original version is also slightly faster than using `getNumericValue` by itself.
- However we can use `charAt` and avoid creating a character array too.

---

**Why is using `divideAndRemainder` slow?**

- `toString` method of `BigInteger` uses a faster algorithm to create the string representation.
- `divideAndRemainder` creates lot of BigInteger objects.

Comment: That 's what i looking for... thanks alot

Comment: @OmarAhmed Updated my answer with code. Also if you want to it would be more fun to write the BigInt yourself ;)

Comment: Looking quickly at the code in divideAndRemainder I'd say this approach results in about 2000 or more unnecessary object creations. Despite toString().toCharArray() creating an unnecessary array I would bet that it'd be much more efficient to do it char by char.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen doesn't `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i))` create temporary objects too? This avoids string conversion all together (except for printing). However I'm now curious to run a benchmark and see. 

Comment: @bhathiya-perera Character.getNumericValue(char) does it without creating an Integer object. Benchmarking with 300 digit number is probably not going to show much difference, though. My point is that divideAndRemainder is more costly than it appears on the surface and that should be taken into account if performance is being thrown around.

Comment: BTW, instead of new BigInteger("2") you should use BigInteger.TWO and BigInteger.TEN or BigInteger.valueOf(int). Those reuse constants when they are available. Not that it matters on single use, but it's a good pattern to learn.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen I've updated the answer with a benchmark. Seems like you are correct. Good catch. :)